# App rejection 22.1

Tags: iphone, ios, appstore-approval

This is second consecutive time that apple has rejected my application citing the following reason.

The below is the reason cited by apple for rejecting my application.

[image]

How to solve this issue. Can anyone please help me to solve it.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you follow the links?

Comment: Yes.But i didnt get any resolution.

Comment: Apply for liscence on territories that you don't have liscence for, or research and find out which territories would not allow it and remove those territories from App Store through iTunes connect and submit your app agin.

Answer (score 1):

---22.1--- code rejection means that Apps must comply with all legal requirements in any location where they are made available to users. It is the developer’s obligation to understand and conform to all local laws

Make sure your app is not doing anything illegal wherever it’s sold. Basically it’s about keeping Apple’s responsibility out of it.

Here is the complety error code related discription of Rejection app take a look this doc [apples-app-store-review-guidelines-annotated-explained](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2010/09/apples-app-store-review-guidelines-annotated-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Any music or copyrighted pictures? Some others brand?